# Atom "The editor has crashed"

Tags: atom

Попытки редактирования в atom вызывают ошибку, скрин с которой я приложил ниже, попытки переустановить программу и очистить реестр не помогли, возможно переустановка ОС поможет, но хочу обойтись без этого. Как решить эту проблему?

[image: Скрин с ошибкой]

Comment: issue запостить пробовали, как предлагают?

Comment: @dIm0n Сам я туда об этом не писал, но искал посты других людей, к сожалению моего знания английского не хватило, чтобы найти решение, поэтому решил спросить тут

Comment: @dIm0n Самый последний пост об этой проблеме опубликовали 17 дней назад, но никто ничего на вопрос не ответил...